# Make an API call using switchMap based on a condition in typeahead of ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, rxjs, ng-bootstrap, typeahead

I am using ng-bootstrap typeahead in my Angular app and want to make an API call to fetch data only if length of the search term in the typeahead is more than 3 characters. The code in my component is

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
  return text$.pipe(      
      debounceTime(200), 
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((searchText) => {
          return this.carsService.getCars(searchText);
      }),
      map(response => {
          return response.cars.map((item: any) => {
            if(item.name === "Porsche") {
              item.name += " - Luxury car";
            }
            else {
              item.name += " - Normal car";
            }
            return item;
          });
      }),
      catchError(error => error)              
  );                 
 }
```

The code in the service file to call the API is

```
getCars(searchText: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}/cars?searchTerm=${searchText}`).pipe(
     map((res: any) => res),
     catchError(error => throwError(error))
  );
}
```

How can I modify the code inside the component to ensure that the API call is made only if the length of the search term entered by user is more than 3 characters and to ensure that empty results are returned and nothing is shown in typeahead results if length of the search term is less than or equal to 3 characters? Please help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a conditional inside your switchMap.
Like so:

```js
distinctUntilChanged(), 
switchMap((searchText) => searchText.length > 3 ? this.carsService.getCars(searchText) : of({cars:[]});
```

You can import `of` from rxjs.

[of](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of)

Comment: I tried the above approach by replacing the code inside switchMap as mentioned above and leaving the logic inside map operator as it is but I get the following error when I start entering into the typeahead: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable

Comment: I think the else case should be `of({cars:[]})`. Otherwise it's probably failing cos it can't find `response.cars` inside the `map`

Comment: Yes it fails because response is empty array in case search term is less than or equal to 3 characters. I have added an if condition inside map to fix the issue:
if(!response.cars) { return []; }. It works perfectly now. Thank you :)

Comment: I wrote this very quickly, thank for noticing, I'll edit my answer

Comment: It will be more convenient to use filter(val => val.length >= 3), before switchMap

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter) operator to your stream

```
  return text$.pipe(      
      debounceTime(200), 
      distinctUntilChanged(),
     filter(val => val.length >= 3),
      switchMap((searchText) => {
          return this.carsService.getCars(searchText);
      }) .....
```

Comment: The filter operator will not clear results if the search term is less than or equal to 3 characters and still shows previous results. Above answer from Ondie works with a slight modification inside map operator as per my comment above. Thank you